# When I run "bin/rails 'x' " in PowerShell, instead of executing the command it asks me which program I want to open it with?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

New to learning Rails. I'm following a tutorial and it has asked me to execute a few commands in the terminal with the format `bin/rails 'x'`, for example `bin/rails server` or `bin/rails generate model Article`. When I run these commands without the `bin/` at the front, it seems to work fine, but when I include that part a pop-up appears asking me which program I would like to open this with. I'm not sure why it's not running in the terminal and is instead trying to run the command in a separate program.

EDIT: I was able to solve the problem by running it like `ruby bin\rails 'x'`

Comment: Windows is a horrible development platform. Use Vagrant + VirtualBox and develop in an Ubuntu VM. WSL (Windows Subsyste for Linux) is also a good alternative.

Comment: I'll look into this for sure. I'm saving up for a Mac and have considered turning this Windows into a Linux. Never does what you need when you need it.

Comment: Doesn't do what you need, if you need it to be Linux or Unix, sure. `rails.exe` is in your `$env:path` as an executable, so PowerShell can find and run it if you just type that name. `bin/rails` is a file called `rails` in a subfolder called `bin` of your current location, which has no file extension and isn't executable. It's found but Windows can't use it. I don't know enough rails arrangement to say why but it sounds like it has both Windows and Nix executables and `bin/rails` is you trying to run the wrong one and Windows can't run it.